# How does a shader detect if two objects overlap

Tags: shaders, procedural

I saw this shader (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2Du5F7PfQM - an animated procedural water toon shader) . It says  (in it's blender market page - https://www.blendermarket.com/products/pure-toon-water) that it makes foam where another object is deforming the object with the shader.
So how does the shader detect that ?

Comment: I would say it's based on Dynamic Paint. Water as canvas ... stones,boat etc as brush. Generated map (texture, weight) is used as factor for mixing material or for displacement.

Comment: It's a lovely shader.. Gleaning clues from the Discord server, it does seem to be using Dynamic Paint. Simple example [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/124117/35559). Other ways of detecting nearby objects might include: masks in the Object space of other objects, Vertex Weight Proximity modifier, with a [wonderful trick](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/109099/35559) to get Vertex Weights into a shader.